# Interaction of fork() and clock_gettime() on Linux 2.6.x

Tags: c, linux

I need to monitor a section of code that includes a fork and I want to confirm that clock_gettime() is documented as working for this scenario.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
starttime = clock_gettime()

if (fork() == 0) {
   /* in the child */
   endtime = clock_gettime()
   print "elapsed time is " endtime - starttime
}
```

I can find example code where this technique is used, but I am concerned that the clock will get reset during the fork, and then the subtraction of endtime and starttime will be meaningless.

This description of fork() mentions reseting some timers, but does not mention how those timers are related to clock_gettime().  By omission, one could assume that it is not affected, but I would like a bit more assurance before I rely on this technique.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

I can write a test program to find out what happens, but I am more interested in finding the documentation on what is defined as the correct behavior.

EDIT: I plan in using CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID and CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW

EDIT 2: I can see in the fork man page that the cpu counters associated with times(2) are reset, but I don't see where the counters for clock_gettime() are reset. I don't see where it is documented that clock_gettime() uses the times(2) counters. If it did, I would think that times(2) would be referenced on the clock_gettime man page.

Comment: You should be OK if you use CLOCK_MONOTONIC (if that is available), and you should be OK with CLOCK_REALTIME too, unless someone with 'appropriate privileges' uses `clock_settime()` on you.  See [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html).

Comment: From the Linux [`fork (...)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) manual page: *" *  Process resource utilizations (getrusage(2)) and CPU time counters (times(2)) are reset to zero in the child."* CPU time is an aggregate of user-mode and kernel-mode time, so resetting those counters is going to affect CPU time reported by anything that asks the kernel.

Comment: See POSIX [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):  _The initial value of the CPU-time clock of the child process shall be set to zero._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct behavior is for `endtime` in the child to be a small, close-to-zero value if you use `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`, since `fork` sets it to zero for the child. For the parent, it will be a value slightly larger than, but almost identical to `starttime`.
This is well-documented in the `fork(2)` manpage, and it is what makes sense too -- you create a new process. The new process has, of course, not consumed any CPU time. It's a newborn process, after all! The parent, on the other hand, has already consumed noticeable CPU and continues doing so, there is no good reason why its counter should be reset to zero (that would be a lie).

Other clocks like `CLOCK_REALTIME` or `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` will not be affected (the former can independently of you forking be modified by a privilegued user, but the latter cannot).
That, too, is according to what common sense tells you. They're global timers, if forking a new process (which happens nearly all the time) was interfering with them, it would be a desaster.

Comment: I can see in the fork man page that the cpu counters associated with times(2) are reset, but I don't see where the counters for clock_gettime() are reset.  I don't see where it is documented that clock_gettime() uses the timer(2) counters.  If it did, I would think that times(2) would be referenced on the clock_gettime man page.  What you write makes sense, but I am still looking for confirmation in documentation.

Comment: One more point about cpu timers being reset: They would not have to be if it is implemented such that the child process gets its starting value from the parent process at the time of the fork, but then accumulates cpu time separately.  It would not be a very friendly implementation, but I don't see the documentation of clock_gettime() that is is reset.  I am inclined to accept your answer, but I am holding off to see if someone can point me to the documentation that unambiguously states it is reset.

Comment: It isn't directly documented that way. POSIX merely says implementations may also support something else but the realtime clock, and SUSv3 states _"Implementations shall support [...] CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, which represents the CPU-time clock of the calling process [...] **amount of execution time of the process associated with the clock**"_. This effectively means the function returns `tms_utime+tms_stime` (without child times), but without explicitly saying that it must use that exact counter (but, of course it does, it would be insane to do any different!). Kerrisk only quotes SUSv3 too.

Comment: Although I a disappointed that explicit documentation does not exist, I am marking this as the accepted answer because it has a good explanation.  My interest in finding documentation on how it works rather than only testing is that I run Linux on processors other than Intel, and this is the kind of thing that can vary.

Comment: I think you're pretty safe. The scheduler must already keep track how much time each process has consumed to be able to make scheduling decisions. There is no way around it, regardless of architecture. The counters for kernel/user time are thus stored somewhere (e.g. the proc table entry) and updated at context switch, and you can read them with `times` (they're the first two fields). These counters readily exist and are accurate. Maintaining a separate counter only for `clock_gettime` would mean extra work for less reliability. It's _possible_, but it would be a very dumb approach.